# How can I run an Azure Function every time a meeting is created in Office 365?

Tags: azure, office365, azure-functions, azure-ad-graph-api

I've been tasked with coming up with a way to insert a link into all of our meeting invites in Office 365.

This link will be different based on the location of the meeting.

At a high level, how can I use something like an Azure function to run some code and act on every meeting object when they are created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly through Azure Function, I don't think it's possible unless you keep querying the office 365 api in order to get the meetings (and compare with previous state to get the new ones).

What you can do is combine Microsoft Flow and office 365, and from the flow, call your azure function.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Easiuest-way-to-get-calendar-id-for-the-Office-365-Calendar/td-p/6279